# json_decode value without quotes

Tags: php, json

Being supplied a feed from external source but the value which is meant to be a number on a few entries is being filled with strings which is breaking looping over them

```
[
  {
    "id": 1001,
    "title": "Test",
    "location": "London",
    "date": "2021-11-11",
    "duration": "",
    "salary": {
      "max": Soon,
      "min": Soon,
    }
  }
]
```

Is there anyway to force `json_decode` to ignore these values and continue or wrap them in quotes?

Comment: No, this is invalid JSON. It must be fixed at the source.

Comment: If `Soon` is the only such value, and isn't likely to occur anywhere else inside actual data, then you might get away with just replacing it first.

Comment: Which value are you talking about specifically? If you mean the `Soon` bits then those aren't strings, they just make the JSON invalid and unreadable by any JSON parser. As trincot says, the source system needs to be fixed. There's absolutely no reason it could not be made to output valid JSON - in fact, if it isn't doing so, it means it's probably using some custom routine to build the JSON which is a big mistake to begin with...there's just no reason not to use a tried and tested library. You _could_ try a find/replace to remove "Soon", but it's just a sticking plaster over the wound.

Comment: We don't have access to the source so only reading from it, their using the same source to populate other platforms which seem to be handling the data fine (just not populating the malformed json parts (salary -> max/min)) - the other problem is it might not just be ```Soon```, it could be anything

Comment: First: you got a valid json? secound post your processing code. this part which iterate the json.

Comment: You could perhaps try using a regex to detect anything between `"max":` and the next `,` which isn't a number and then swapping it for `null` or whatever you want. Maybe find out how these other platforms are handling it. But you should still report it to the maintainers of the source system because it's just not good enough in 2021 to be outputting invalid JSON in a live system.

Comment: What other platforms are processing this? Show me a JSON lib that doesn't reject it.  jq, node.js, perl, python, raku, ruby... they all choke on the "Soon"s.

Comment: HTML has spoiled developers. You wouldn't expect anyone to consume a corrupted Excel spreadsheet or a corrupted PDF file. The way to think about this problem is that you have a custom data format that resembles JSON and could eventually be transformed to JSON so you're able to use JSON tools. Unfortunately, you don't know the format specs so you'll have to reverse-engineer from samples and, still, format may change unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having a similar problem we ended up regex replacing anything between min & max into quotes to stop any potential error, can then convert back into an int if needed

```
$pattern = array('/"max":(.*?),/is', '/"min":(.*?),/is'); 
$replace = array('"max":"$1",', '"min":"$1",');
$replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $json);
```